# Ajax Live search post to Laravel view

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

I'm creating a Live Search from a view and I'm wondering why I'm getting a No Response Data Available, even though the header shows it's sending the data after post. My search bar is in templates/reports.blade.php:

```
           <div class="large-6 columns">
            <input type="text" id="search-input" onkeyup="searchup()" onkeydown="searchdown()" placeholder="Search Recipient"></div>
            <div id="search-results"></div>
```

The js script is this:

```
var timer;
function searchup() {
 timer = setTimeout(function()
 {
    var keywords = $('#search-input').val();
    if (keywords.length > 0)
    {
        $.post('/reports/executeSearch', {keywords: keywords}, function(markup)
        {
            $('#search-results').html(markup);
        });
    }
 }, 500);
}

function searchdown()
{
    clearTimeout(timer);
}
```

My route is this:

```
    Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
    Route::resource('reports', 'ReportsController');
    Route::post('reports/executeSearch', ['uses' => 'ReportsController@search']);
    });
```

While my Controller is this:

```
public function index()
    {
        // get all the reports
        $reports = Reports::all();

        // load the view and pass the reports
        return View::make('templates.reports')
            ->with('reports', $reports);
    }

    public function search(Request $keyword)
    {
        $searchUsers = Recipients::where("name", "iLIKE", "%{$keyword->get('keywords')}%");
        return View::make('templates.searchUsers')->with('searchUsers', $searchUsers);

    }
```

As you can see, it sends data to templates/searchUsers.blade.php which is a simple loop:

```
@foreach($searchUsers as $key => $value)
    <b>{{ $value->name }}</b>
    <br>
@endforeach
```

But for some reason, it doesn't seem to append inside my reports.blade.php. Do I just insert it via js?

Comment: use `.fail()` for error handling. Your request is perhaps returning with a non 200 status.

Comment: it's a 200 OK status. What does it mean?

Comment: can you see the response in developer toolbar (in chrome) or firefox?

Comment: here it is.. http://imgur.com/nyQSY6B

Comment: I'm getting 200 ok (http://imgur.com/j1Ei4mD) and the 'keyword' is passed along fine..I'm just not sure if a separate blade can be used for such.

Comment: Put `Route::post('reports/executeSearch', ['uses' => 'ReportsController@search']);` above `Route::resource('reports', 'ReportsController');`. Right now, your request is probably going to `ReportsController@show` which probably doesn't return anything.

Comment: I'm getting a 500 Internal error when I did that..ReflectionException in Route.php line 280:
Method App\Http\Controllers\ReportsController::show() does not exist

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112326/discussion-between-itachi-and-odinovsky).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it's because you didn't get the collection from the query builder with `get()`.

Try:

```
$searchUsers = Recipients::where("name", "iLIKE", "%{$keyword->get('keywords')}%")->get();
```

Comment: I forgot to include that..Thanks for noticing. :)